# Responsive Table by Columns on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a table that looks like this below

```
+--------------------------------------+
|  Title A   |   Title B  |   Title C  | 
+------------+------------+------------+
| Content A1 | Content B1 | Content C1 |
+------------+------------+------------+
| Content A2 | Content B2 | Content C2 |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8m22kLu/5/)

and would like to format this table to be view on mobile device like

```
+------------+
|  Title A   |
+------------+
| Content A1 |
+------------+
| Content A2 |
+------------+
+------------+
|  Title B   |
+------------+
| Content B1 |
+------------+
| Content B2 |
+------------+
+------------+
|  Title C   |
+------------+
| Content C1 |
+------------+
| Content C2 |
+------------+
```

Is this possible to do with CSS? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?  You can edit your question to add the code that you've tried to run, and any errors or results you get.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to change the HTML or are you looking to just change the CSS?

If you can change the HTML:

`JSFiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/g8m22kLu/11/
(Please resize the jsfiddle window to stack the table)

As Dreamwalker has mentioned bootstrap is very good at this and will show/hide columns by viewport width and wrap columns for you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can accomplish this with CSS.  However, you are further ahead integrating a framework for responsive design, I like to use http://getbootstrap.com/

Then the display settings are more consistent across all display devices.